# Extrude SVG Path Text to 3D Mesh

Tags: three.js

Using the code available on the example: `webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2.html`, I'm trying to extrude svg text (created with path) to three.js shapes.

This is what my '[.svg](http://jsbin.com/yogoyecupu/1/edit)' looks like:

[image]

This is what I get when using the `function transformSVGPath()` inside the example:

[image]

As a good boy, I have already researched a lot before come here and ask.
I saw [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4590) that the text tool inside three.js  (which I am not using) expects clockwise winding for outer solid and counter clockwise for the holes. My font considers that, even why if it doesn't consider, my svg would look weird and funny because of the [svg-fill rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html)

Why am I doing all this instead use TextGeometry? At the moment the text tool in three.js doesn't support font kerning and this is a important requirement for me.

I would say that `transformSVGPath()` is not doing what I expect. Anyone to help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extrude a `<path d="...">` which has `moveto (M or m)` commands in it and compose holes, make sure that the outer solid lines are  counterclockwise direction and that the inner hole lines are clockwise direction. This is the opposite of what the SVG specification says but works when using the `function transformSVGPath()`.